How can I find the correct extension for a file without one?
I have a large number of files with no extension on my android device. I do not know how I got them, probably by downloading. If, from the file name and date, I can guess what extension they should have, I can usually get them to open by adding that extension manually.
Does anyone know of an app, or a command, that examines a file and returns a filetype? Ideally one that can then append the correct extension.
I believe most of these files are probably ebooks, PDFs, or some kind of media. If any of them are actually exes, I want to delete them, not run them.

Files in the shared media section can not be executed. That means even an APK would have to be first installed before it could be executed. Of course malicious media files exploiting an app of the media service would also be possible.

Use file command.

Possible dupe: Determining file type from Android terminal emulator
